# Cayley-Hamilton equation for a given matrix $A$ and other matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

We know  that "every square matrix over a commutative ring (such as the real or complex field) satisfies its own characteristic polynomial" i.e.

$p(A)=0$

My question is:

- what other matrices are satisfying this particular equation $p(A)=0$

Evidently it is satisfied  by any matrix which is generated from $A$ through a change of basis and also by some more simply generated matrices, for example $A^T$ or $\lambda_i{I}$, where $\lambda_i $ is eigenvalue for matrix $A$.
But maybe *it is possible* to find a general form of the matrix which is satisfying characteristic equation generated for a matrix A?

Comment: @learnmore  Thank you learnmore for the answer and edition: the word "equation" was taken from wikipedia.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem however If you consider that more appropriate is polynomial let it be..

Comment: Suppose the field is $\mathbb{C}$. You can find all possible Jordan forms that satisfy a given polynomial $p$. All other matrices $A$ for which $p(A)=0$ will be similar to these Jordan matrices. For the field $\mathbb{R}$, rational canonical form is appropriate.

Comment: @TrialAndError And how, starting from matrix $A$, to generate  these forms ?, let's say for R field...

Comment: Welcome.I hope my edit and my answer both will help you@Widawensen

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Real_matrices describes a canonical form for real matrices.

Comment: @learnmore Yes, they are valuable remarks, I upvoted them although I would prefer answer with more explicit formulas for generating such matrices, starting from A matrix..

Comment: @Widawensen;I have added an $\text{iff}$ criteria;Do have a look and let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All those matrices which have the same characteristic polynomial as that of $A$ will surely satisfy the equation $p(A)=0$ viz. $A^T$,any matrix similar to $A$ as you have pointed out.

*A matrix $B$ will satisfy the characteristic polynomial of $A\iff$  the minimal polynomial of $B$  divides the characteristic polynomial of $A$*.

Let the characteristic polynomial of $A$ be $\lambda_A(x)$ and the minimal polynomial of $B$ be $m_B(x)$.

The minimal polynomial of $B$  divides the characteristic polynomial of $A\implies \lambda_A(x)=m_B(x)q(x)\implies m_B(A)q(A)=0$

Since we are in a field $m_B(A)q(A)=0\implies m_B(A)=0$.

Conversely suppose that the minimal polynomial of $B$ satisfies the characteristic polynomial of $A\implies m_B(A)=0$.

**To show :** $m_B(x)\text{divides } \lambda_A(x)$.

Proof:The characteristic polynomial of $A,\lambda_A(x)$ annihilates $B$  and the minimal polynomial of $B,m_B(x)$ divides any annihilating polynomial of $B $ and hence $m_B(x)\text{divides } \lambda_A(x)\text{Q.E.D.}$

Comment: @learmore Thank you, learnmore for extension  your answer. I'm still studying it..it's very enligthening and  leads me to more questions..

Comment: Really happy to help you @Widawensen

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we work over fields. $p(T) = 0$ if and only if the minimal polynomial $m_T$ of $T$ divides $p$, i.e. there is a polynomial $q\in\mathbb{F}[\lambda]$ with $p = q\cdot m_T$. So the question comes down to: which linear operators have a minimal polynomial that divides $p$? Which begs the question, given a polynomial $m$, what linear operators have $m$ as their minimal polynomial?

For each factor $q$ of $p$, one can find at least one matrix whose minimal polynomial is $q$, namely the companion matrix to $q$.

If $\mathbb{F}$ is a field where polynomials split into linear factors (e.g. $\mathbb{C}$), then the Jordan form is well-defined for all linear operators. The minimal polynomial in this case also factors. The minimal polynomial restricts the Jordan form of the operator in the following way: the degree of each linear factor corresponds to the size of the largest Jordan block. So for example, if $(\lambda-1)^3$ is a factor of $m_T(\lambda)$, then the Jordan canonical form of $T$ is a matrix with at least one $3\times 3$ Jordan block of eigenvalue $1$. These are the only restrictions placed on the Jordan form by the minimal polynomial.

Since there are only finitely many possible factors of $p$, if $p(T) = 0$ then there are only finitely many possible minimal polynomials for $T$. If we also fix the $k$ so that $T$ is a linear mapping $\mathbb{F}^k\to\mathbb{F}^k$, then for each choice of minimal polynomial there are only finitely many possible Jordan forms for $T$. You can thus use the Jordan forms to explicitly classify all operators that annihilate $p$.

The above discussion relies heavily on the fact that $\mathbb{F}[\lambda]$ is a principal ideal domain (namely so that $m_T$ is defined). If we take coefficients in a commutative ring that is not a field then the above will likely fail.